# Semantic Hashing Implementation

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoders, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I'm trying to compute semantic hashes for a set of articles as described in  this [paper by Ruslan and Hinton](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bonner/courses/2016s/csc321/readings/Semantic%20Hashing.pdf).

I've found an existing implementation [here](https://github.com/gynnash/AutoEncoder) but it crashes while loading a file named **zhidao_weights.mat**. I've trouble understanding what this file is supposed to contain and how to fix this issue. Also could someone explain what the input format is supposed to be?

If there's a more readable, comprehensive and working implementation of this paper then please refer it.

Comment: If you are just asking for code, that would be off topic here. However, questions about how to compute semantic hashes would be on topic. You may want to edit to clarify your question.